# Apache POI leer celda formato hora 00:00:00

Tags: java, apache-poi

Uso Apache POI XSSFWorkbook, al leer una celda con formato: `12:55` lo identifica como numérico y me devuelve `Numero(0.010416666666666666)`.

```
XSSFSheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();

SimpleDateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

Map<String, MedidaCabBean> cabecera;
ArrayList<MedidaDetalleBean> det = new ArrayList<>();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Row currentRow = iterator.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();

        if (currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
            System.out.print("texto("+currentCell.getStringCellValue() + ")--");
        } else if (currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {

            if (HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(currentCell)) {
                System.out.print("Fecha("+formateador.format(currentCell.getDateCellValue())+") ");
            } else {
                System.out.print("Numero("+currentCell.getNumericCellValue() + ")--");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo identificar si una celda es de tipo hora?

Comment: que te retorna si ocupas [HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(double)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DateUtil.html#getJavaDate-double-) en el valor numerico retornado por `currentCell.getNumericCellValue()` ?

Comment: @Klaimmore pues me sale la fecha + hora. la hora bien! Si quieres ponlo como respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No me gusta mucho esta respuesta, pero la pondré de todas formas:

Apache POI reconoce algunos [tipos de celda](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html), tales como:

- _NONE
- BLANK
- BOOLEAN
- ERROR
- FORMULA
- NUMERIC
- STRING

Lamentablemente no existe un tipo Date. Las fechas se almacenan en excel como numeros `double` y por tanto su tipo es `NUMERIC`

Apache POI provee algunos metodos para determinar si una celda podría ser Date:

- `DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(Cell cell)`:

  > true si parece una fecha
- `DateUtil.isCellInternalDateFormatted(Cell cell)`

  > true si utiliza un formato interno de fecha

Para interpretar una fecha a partir del numero ingresado en la celda con `double num = cell.getNumericCellValue()` existen unos cuantos metodos mas:

- `DateUtil.getJavaDate(double date)`

  > retorna null si no es una fecha excel valida
- `DateUtil.getJavaDate(double date, boolean use1904windowing)`

  > igual que el anterior, pero considerando que el archivo puede utilizar el sistema de fechas basado en 1904 ([por defecto en mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel))

Y otras 2 versiones que incluyen el `TimeZone` en el cual interpretar la fecha y hora.

Y por ultimo, los fuentes de poi (al menos en su version 3.7) implementa el metodo `HSSFCell.getDateCellValue()` como:

```
public Date getDateCellValue() {

    if (_cellType == CellType.BLANK) {
        return null;
    }
    double value = getNumericCellValue();
    if (_book.getWorkbook().isUsing1904DateWindowing()) {
        return HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(value, true);
    }
    return HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(value, false);
}
```

Por lo que, convendría de todas formas tratar de interpretar la celda como Date mediante este metodo si es que el tipo de celda es `NUMERIC`.